# stop a c program from launching another program

Tags: java, c, bash

I am doing a project for which I need to compile a C program , run it over a test data and then produce it's output. I use two bash scripts , first clearscript.sh which removes the temprory files from current directory( code.c, input, output ) and myscript.sh which compiles code.c , runs it over the input file and produces the output which I show in the text area in my GUI.

Now my problem is that, how do I stop the user from doing things like executing system("rm *"), because that would do terrible things. One way is that I can search the string corresponding to system command and if found then I won't allow the program to run. But I feel that there must be a better solution to stop execution of a external program through a C program.

Another problem is that when the program runs through a infinite loop the program stop responding. And I feel that there are many more problems which I will discover later. Is there any better approach to do what my program is doing.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;



    class test2 {

    static         JTextArea ta1,ta2,ta0;

    public static class myEvent implements ActionListener

      {

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

                    { 

                            try{

                                    Process p = new ProcessBuilder("./cleanscript.sh").start();
                                    p.waitFor();
                                    }
                            catch(Exception e1)
                                    {}                                

                            try{

                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("code.c"));
                                    ta1.write(bw);
                               }
                            catch (IOException ioe)
                            {        
                                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                            }



                            try{
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("input"));
                                    ta0.write(bw);
                            }
                            catch(IOException ioe)
                            {
                                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                            }





                            try{
                            Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("./myscript.sh").start();
                            pb.waitFor();
                            }
                            catch(Exception t)
                                    {}




                            try {

                                    ta2.read(new FileReader(new File("output")),"fun");
                            }
                            catch (IOException ioe2)
                            {
                                    ioe2.printStackTrace();
                            }



                      }
    }




    public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame jf;



    jf = new JFrame();


    jf.setLocationByPlatform(true);

    ta0 = new JTextArea("Give Input to the program here,before running the program");
    ta1 = new JTextArea("Your C program here",0,100);
    ta2 = new JTextArea("Your output will be shown here");

    ta2.setEditable(false);




    JScrollPane jsp0,jsp1,jsp2;


    jsp0 = new JScrollPane(ta0);
    jsp1 = new JScrollPane(ta1);
    jsp2 = new JScrollPane(ta2);




    jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

    jf.getContentPane().add(jsp1);
    jf.getContentPane().add(jsp0);
    jf.getContentPane().add(jsp2);



    JButton jb = new JButton("Run");

    jb.addActionListener(new myEvent());


    jf.getContentPane().add(jb);



    jf.setSize(1000,400);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }}
```

code for cleanscript.sh

```
     rm code.c
     rm input
     rm output
```

code for myscript.sh

```
     cc code.c
     ./a.out < input > output
```

Comment: The normal way to protect a C program from the rest of the system is to use `chroot`  This changes the root the program can see and limits it to the directory you specify.  You can also make the files read only and redirect the output to your Java program so it doesn't write to a file at all.

Comment: For the infinite loop problem, you could kill it after *n* seconds. But be aware this is an uphill battle.

Comment: I thought Online Judges do it all the time. Accept code in C. Then there must be a easy solution to the problem.

Comment: Along with the feedback from Peter,BoppreH and vonbrand I have decided to create a new directory for each compilation, so that Even if something happens due to malicious code, my whole integrity is not lost. Plus, I am going to keep my original regex search approach too. Thanks a lot guys. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to run some external programs, set up a list of *allowed* programs, and check that what is being given is in your list. *Do not* use `system(3)`, that calls a shell to run the command (and that is quite easy to fool), use one of the `exec(3)` family. More details on what to look out for security-wise is [here](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs).

Comment: Okay.. I will see into it and accept the answer when I solve my problem :)